# DeMorgan's law for three events

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be three events. How to prove De Morgan's law for them, i.e.,

$$(A\cup B\cup C)^c=A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c =(A\cup B)^c \cap C^c?$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align} (A\cup B\cup C)^c & = \Big(\color{blue}{(A\cup B)} \cup \color{red} {C}\Big)^c \tag{associativity}\\ \\
& = \color{blue}{(A \cup B)^c} \cap \color{red}{C^c} \tag{DeMorgan's: 2 sets}\\ \\
& = \color{blue}{(A^c \cap B^c)} \cap C^c \tag{DeMorgan's: 2 sets}\\ \\
& = A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c \tag{associativity}\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice color coding and response! +1

Answer (score 5):

Do you know DeMorgan's Laws for two events? If so, then here's a hint: $$A\cup B\cup C=(A\cup B)\cup C$$