# Prove: (A∩B∩C)'=(A'∪B'∪C')

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How to prove that Prove: (A ∩ B ∩ C)'=(A'∪ B'∪ C') by first using Associative Law to insert brackets, and then using DeMorgan’s Law?

Thankyou!

Comment: **Hint**: assume $A∩B=D$, then use DeMorgarn's law.

Comment: LHS:
Taking A∩B=D
(A ∩ B ∩ C)'
(D∩C)'
De Morg
D' ∪ C'
(A∩B)'∪C'
A' U B' U C'

Is this correct?

Comment: What I meant was: $(A ∩ B ∩ C)'=(D ∩ C)'=...$ but I answered your question you can see it below.

Comment: **Duplicate:** [DeMorgan's Law for three sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496499/demorgans-law-for-three-events/496517#496517).  Another duplicate: [algebraic proof of DeMorgans Law with three sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437831/algebraic-proof-of-de-morgans-law-with-three-sets/437832?s=1|35.9336#437832)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(A ∩ B ∩ C)'=((A ∩ B) ∩ C)'=(A ∩ B)'∪ C'=(A'∪ B') ∪ C'=A'∪ B' ∪ C'$